# Why can't I save apps into my SD-card?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, insufficient-memory

I have a problem with my lenovo S750.
When I want to download something the system says:

> Memory Full, Not enough storage space

It's really frustrating since I cannot use the android at all!

My phone is *rooted*, and I already tried to use *Clean Master* to move all of my apps to the SD-card, but it only moved 5 apps for me, but other than that, there is no apps on the SD-card, only photos and few videos.
The rest is probably still on the internal memory.

- [Internal storage is full (1GB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgLBn.png)
- [micro-SD card is half empty(2GB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEKBy.png)
- [phone storage is empty (1.55GB of total 1.64GB free)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFion.png)

Since internal storage is full, no apps will be updated due to lack of storage.

Furthermore, how can I take advantage of the *phone storage*?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083709/android-emulator-sdcard-push-error-read-only-file-system/40449314#40449314

Answer (score 0):

You have to wipe your cache partition. It is the partition where Android stores downloaded .APKs and some other system data and you cannot see it with a file manager.

**Step 1**

Turn off your Android device. Reboot the phone or tablet into Recovery Mode. The process is specific to the device model. For Lenovo S750:

- Press and hold Volume Up and Power Button at the same time.
- Release all buttons when the Lenovo S750 screen flickers and in a few seconds the Recovery screen will appear.
- When the Android image appears press Power shortly

**Step 2**

Press the “Volume-down” button to scroll to “Wipe Data/Factory Reset.”, select it.

**Step 3**

Scroll to and select “Wipe Cache Partition.”

**Step 4**

Highlight and select “Reboot System Now.” The phone restarts.

DO NOT make "Factory reset". You will loose all your data on phone.

Comment: What partition do I to wipe the cache? the internal or the SD-card one? they both have a Download folders

Comment: It is NOT a Download folder. It is a system partition in internal flash memory that you CANNOT see.